# Error while loading Xamarin forms PCL project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

It was working fine until this error came up:

Tools > Options > Xamarin (iOS and Android settings)

> 'An error occurred while loading this page property'

I am not able to create or load the existing xamarin forms PCL project. I am using Xamarin with Visual Studio IDE. I tried to modify, repair and uninstall and install for 3 times at least but the same error comes up.

There is also one more error when loading the PCL project which says:

> Error: this template attempted to load component assembly 'xamarin.forms.templates.VisualStudio'

Please help!

Comment: It would be useful if you could include a pastebin link to your full version information (Help > About Visual Studio > Copy Info) and your IDE log that exhibits those errors (probably latest log in %LOCALAPPDATA%\Xamarin\Logs).

Comment: One more thing I found that there is no Xamarin Account option in visual studio (Tools- Xamarin Account) where one can login with their xamarin account. These are the details you asked for Log : http://pastebin.com/whHGr34i          Version Details : http://pastebin.com/EAP68U8E @AlanClark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Xamarin and potentially the JDK / Android SDK aren't installed correctly here as your version information does not list the Xamarin components.  As such I would recommend a thorough uninstall and reinstall of Xamarin and related Android components.

1. Close Visual Studio and follow the Xamarin [Thorough Uninstall](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/visual_studio_with_xamarin/troubleshooting/uninstall-xamarinvs/) guide to remove all Xamarin files.  This is a comprehensive process so please ensure you follow all the steps.
2. Remove the Android SDK Tools entirely. You should be able to do this from `Settings > Apps & Features`.
3. *Optional:* It appears you're using JDK 1.7 which is fine for Android APIs <= 23, but for full API 24 support you will require **JDK 1.8 64 bit**.  As such, I would recommend installing [JDK 1.8 64 bit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).  You can install this alongside JDK 1.7 but since it is backwards compatible it is generally safe to uninstall the previous version.
4. Download and install the [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads) *command line tools* from Google's website.
5. Download and install the latest Xamarin.VisualStudio installer from the Downloads section of [your Xamarin account](https://store.xamarin.com/account/me/subscription/downloads) (you can sign up free of charge if you need to):

[image]

6. Start Visual Studio and navigate to Tools > Options > Xamarin > Android and ensure the paths are pointing to the correct locations for the JDK, SDK and NDK.  It should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @AlanClark  its working fine now. marked as answer !!